# How to put some divs in a row?

Tags: css, html, row, inline

I'm trying to put two divs without a linebreak between them.

this is the html:

```
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"></div>

            <div id="left">
                <div id="slideshow"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
    #header {
    background-color: #13768a;
    width: 962px;
    height: 207px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    clear: both;
}


#logo {
    background-image:url('logo.png');
    height: 207px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

    #left {
    width:712px;
    height: 207px;
}

#slideshow {
    background-color: #137387;
    width: 686px;
    height: 144px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

the problem is that I want it to look like this:
[How I want it to look like](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/8357/indexrecovered.png)

But it looks like this:
[How it looks like](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/6053/77002607.png)

Comment: can you tell us which two divs you want without linebreak

Comment: "left" and "logo". (and "slideshow" but he is inside "left")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introduce a `float` CSS property. Change CSS as below, for `#logo` and `#left`.

```
#logo {
  background-image:url('logo.png');
  height: 207px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float:right;
}

#left {
  width:712px;
  height: 207px;
  float:left;
}
```

---

From the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float),

> The **float** CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Answer (score 11):

This is controlled by the [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) style property. Normally, `div` elements use `display: block`. You can use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` instead if you want them on the same horizontal line.

Example using `inline-block` ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/uxiyol) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uxiyol/edit#html)):

CSS:

```
.ib {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ib">Div #1</div>
<div class="ib">Div #2</div>
```

Comment: When I use display: inline;
I then all the divs are just missing... exept the div "header"
When I use display: inlie-block; it looks just like it looks now...

Comment: @DorAharonson: That's because of the `margin: auto` and also the fact that you have very wide divs. You'll have to play with that a bit, possibly put the header inside something else. `inline-block` is probably what you want, or possibly `float: left` (but you'll have to play with that as well), possibly both.

Answer (score 2):

Div elements normally use `display:block` which forces a line break before and after the element.If you want to remove the line breaks , you can use `display:inline` which will display elements horizontally.Make the div's display property to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` you want to appear horizontally .

Comment: When I use display: inline;
I then all the divs are just missing... exept the div "header"
When I use display: inlie-block; it looks just like it looks now...

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
#logo {
    background-image:url('logo.png');
    height: 207px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:right;}

#left {
    position:relative;
    width:712px;
    height: 207px;
}

#slideshow {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    background-color: #137387;
    width: 686px;
    height: 144px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}​
```

Basically I put a `float:right;` on the logo to position it right, then added `position:relative` to the `#left` div and `position:absolute` to the `#slideshow` div. This way you can adjust the `top` and `left` attributes to position the slideshow anywhere you want it.

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline` is the css style that you need to use.

Comment: When I use display: inline;
I then all the divs are just missing... exept the div "header"
When I use display: inlie-block; it looks just like it looks now...

Comment: that is because of the unnatural width and height that you have set.. fix that